# Using Charts in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part, chart-web-part

I want to use a custom chart in SharePoint which picks up data from a list? I have not worked with SharePoint charts can anyone give me an example of a working chart? And also if there are many methods to do it then please tell me which is the best method. I'm mostly looking for a visual webpart.

And also i want to know more about how to use webpartpage chartviewwebpart?

```
<WebPartPages:ChartViewWebPart ID="ChartViewWebPart1" runat="server"></WebPartPages:ChartViewWebPart>
```

Comment: I used a similar type development back in 2007, used an existing WebPart off of one of the project sites (CodePlex, SourceForge, etc) and then modified it to what i needed.  In either case, it was a Farm Solution cause the Parts library needed to be in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article to create charts in SharePoint hosted app

http://tomvangaever.be/blogv2/2014/03/how-to-create-charts-from-sharepoint-2013-list/

> And also i want to know more about how to use webpartpage chartviewwebpart?

Below link helps to use the webparts in apps

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/08/working-with-web-parts-within.html

Comment: Please do not post link only answers, try instead to add some details from the links and use the links merely as a source of more details information